# Removing cart products in page load

Tags: magento-1.9, php, controllers

Would there be any way to remove cart products from your id on page load? I'm working on it, I researched a lot too, but I found almost nothing that could help me to do a function to remove products from the cart according to its id in loading or reloading the page, since this was something specific, since only you can have a product of a category in each request and I wish I could handle that exception that exists. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you be clearer in your question please ? because psk is really blurry

Comment: @Prince I wrote the question again, now being more clear and objective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you want but, if i understand well you want to remove some product from cart according to the `id` if this product.

```
$productId = 10; // the product id that you want to remove it

$cart  = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
$items = $cart->getCart()->getItems();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if ($item->getProduct()->getId() == $productId) {
        $itemId = $item->getItemId();
        $cart->getCart()->removeItem($itemId)->save();
        break;
    }
}
```